# Given two IPv6 addresses, how can I be sure that they are connected to the same router?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

If I understand it right, two computers with IPv6 addresses that are connected to the same router share their subnet ID. However, that subnet ID can be given also to computers connected to other routers.

Thus, is there a way to determine that two computers are connected to the same router (given IPv6 addresses only)?

Comment: What does “connected to the same router,” mean? Computers don’t connect to routers. Routers move packets between different networks. Networks can have multiple routers in the same subnet. There are default gateways and static/dynamic routes. Do you mean, which router is the computer sending it’s packets through to get to the internet? Then it is the same as an IPv4 network. What IP address is the default gateway? That is your answer.

Comment: No, it's not the answer. Because there is a possibility that I send my packets via other router that has the same subnet ID.

Comment: That’s basically what I just said. But why would that happen unless you have multiple routers on the same subnet and static / dynamic routes setup on your devices? It’s not clear what you’re asking. This is all basic networking, it doesn’t change just because it’s ipv6. If you want to know where packets go look at your routing table.

Comment: I want to determine device location based on IP data. When I see in my data two devices moved packets via the same IPv4 address, I know that the packets were moved through the same router. However, when I see the same situation with IPv6 addresses, I can't be sure, because as you said networks can have multiple routers in the same subnet. Thus, I am asking if there is a way to locate the router or determine devices location based on IPv6 data. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, that subnet ID can be given also to computers connected to other routers.

Not in global IPv6.

If you’re asking “Given two IPv6 addresses (but not subnet masks), can I know whether these hosts are in the same network?”, the answer is no. They’re more likely to be on the same network if they’re in the same /64, but it’s not guaranteed. This is unchanged from IPv4.

If you’re asking “Give my IPv6 address and subnet mask and another IPv6 address, can I know whether these hosts are in the same network?”, the answer is yes, absolutely. From your address + subnet, you know the entire range of addresses that are local. If, for whatever reason (ULA, ...) the target host is *not* on your local network, you will not be able to reach it. This is unchanged from IPv4.

Re your comments:

> When I see in my data two devices moved packets via the same IPv4 address, I know that the packets were moved through the same router.

It is likely, yes. They can still be in entirely different locations.

> However, when I see the same situation with IPv6 addresses, I can't be sure, because as you said networks can have multiple routers in the same subnet.

You can also have multiple routers on an IPv4 network.

Also, keep in mind that traffic typically traverses dozens of routers before reaching its target on the internet.